# How to validate a sum of percentage from multiple fields before creating a new item?

Tags: jquery, validation

Here's the situation that I'm facing. I have three (number-type) fields which should add up to 100%.

What I want is to be able to dynamically validate that after I input the number into the 3 fields. Should the total in three fields not add up to 100%, Sharepoint will not allow the user to Save the item.

Is is possible to do so with jquery/javascript?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: while this is surely possible - js solutions cannot force behavior. Why not using a custom validation as seen here http://summit7systems.com/how-to-conditionally-require-data-in-sharepoint-columns/

Comment: what do you mean by js solutions cannot force behaviour?

Comment: @Gwny well someone could easily disable or manipulate the code to save the value. Also when the user creates list items via rest there is no JS to force conditions. Look at my answer to see how its done better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use validation settings for that - something like `=IF(Num1+Num2+Num3<=100,"OK","Not OK")` should totally work and will prevent the user from saving.

Here's some reference for the formulas - https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-in/article/Examples-of-common-formulas-in-SharePoint-Lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3?ui=en-US&rs=en-IN&ad=IN

You can find the option in the list settings:

[image]

Result Inline Editing:
[image]

Result NewForm:
[image]

Comment: You can't use other columns in column validation. So I don't think this will work.

Comment: @Akhoy I actually tested my formular - what do you mean with "can't use other columns"?

Comment: When I tested, it shows me a message like this: The formula cannot refer to another column.  Check the formula for spelling mistakes or update the formula to reference only this column.

Comment: Nevermind. My bad. I was testing it under column validation.

Comment: Actually this really works for me. Many thanks to you @Akhoy!!

Comment: @Naiht I think you meant Mx. :)

Comment:   glad I could help you