# SharePoint look up value A (list number value) and hide Add New button if 2nd list count value B (list count) is equal or greater to value A

Tags: javascript, infopath

I have an InfoPath form displaying formation for a commuter sign up list called "Register Commute" I modified the Content Type Display Form and added a list called "Commuter Sign Up" which is associated to the "Register Commute" list through look up column associated. I was then able to connect the 2 web parts through a web part data connection so when an Commute travel is selected it shows folks that are signed up in the display form. AWESOME and works great!

My issue is that I would like to programmatically hide the Add New button in the Commuter Sign Up when the list count (List Count) and the Available Seats field (List Numerical Value) is equal... Please see the image.

Help is greatly appreciated!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAGS4.png

Comment: your SO question got migrated - please avoid posting duplicates on multiple SE plattforms http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/156183/sharepoint-look-up-value-a-list-number-value-and-hide-add-new-button-if-2nd-li

Comment: I appreciate your response... A helpful answer would have been more greatly appreciated. :-)

Comment: you are trying to prevent Items with certain conditions?  (no Item allowed where colA is greater colB for example)?

Comment: I'm trying to prevent Items to be added if 2 datasets are equal or greater than a key value.... I have a column called Number of seats. When the item count on the list items are equal to or greater than I'd like to run some css that will hide the add new button.

Comment: you can have a lot of fun with list Validation - but Im not sure this helps you here. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/154243/10271

Comment: No it doesn't help... I need JavaScript to interrogate the elements on the page and then inject some css when the condition is met but thanks.

Comment: Can you find an xpath to that `4` after `Available Seats:`? Then javascript compare-and-hide side gets easy. But I'd rather create a custom webpart to the second one to have more control